# Jekyll/Liquid/gh-pages, string as char array?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, liquid

Get an **array of every character in a string**,
is it available?

My code attempting to do (but failed):

```
{% assign a = "ABC" | split "" %}
{{ a | join ',' }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt is correct, is just the syntax that is not correct.

```
{% assign a = "ABC" | split: "" %}

{{ a | join: ',' }}
```